# Listview populates on first load, but not if you visit page by clicking a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite, listview, air

I'm just learning Adobe Air with JQuery, and I'm using some sample code from a Sitepoint tutorial.  I've encountered a rather unusual problem.  If I view the page with the list view by using the "Preview in Adobe Air" option in Dreamweaver, it populates fine.  If I navigate away from the page and come back to it, the listview doesn't populate, and the rest of the javascript on the page stops working.

This is the code for populating the listview:

```
function ListNotes() {

var notes = GetNotes();
$("#notes").empty();    
var numRecords = notes.data.length;

for (i=0;i<numRecords;i++) {                  
    $('#student-list').append("<li><a href=\"#\">"+unescape(notes.data[i].name)+" "+unescape(notes.data[i].lastseen)+"<br \/>"+unescape(notes.data[i].belt)+"<br \/>Last Session: <\/a><\/li>");
}
$('#student-list').listview('refresh');
$(".note_time a").click(function(){
    var currHash = $(this).attr("href").split('/');
    var id = currHash[1];

    var dbQuery = new air.SQLStatement();
    dbQuery.sqlConnection = db;
    dbQuery.text = "DELETE FROM students WHERE id=" + id;

    try {
        dbQuery.execute();
    } catch (error) {
        air.trace("Error deleting note from DB:", error);
        air.trace(error.message);
        return;
    }

    ListNotes();
});
```

}

The listview goes inside a div:

```
<div data-role="content" data-theme="a"><ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="student-list" data-filter="true"></ul></div>
```

There's a snippet in notes.js that populates the listview:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    BindEvents();
    CreateMenus();
    SetupDB();

    ListNotes();
});
```

The page works fine on first loading via "Preview in Adobe Air", but doesn't work at all if you navigate to it via clicking a button inside the app. I suspect I'm missing something really obvious but would appreciate any tips.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried .on('click'... instead of .click?

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
$(".note_time a").on('click', function(){
    //your code here
});
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks.  I tried that, it doesn't seem to have made any difference though.

I might have confused matters by leaving that bit of the code snippet in. The listview loads fine first try, but if I navigate away from the page and then come back to it, the list doesn't load.

This is what I want to happen (searchable list):


http://postimg.org/image/g2uiujzub/

This is what happens if you click on Class at the bottom to load the page:

http://postimg.org/image/5j5ydclyx/

Thanks again

Comment: When you navigate away, does it refresh the page on re-entry? or is it a single page app

Comment: Thanks.
I've tried adding some code to make the page reload once, since it wasn't doing that - it's still coming up with a blank list when you navigate to it via that button.

Comment: When returning to the list, is GetNotes() returning the data you need? Is ListNotes() even being triggered?

Comment: Thanks - I just tested it and the entire document.ready is not triggering when you navigate to the page. It's loading OK the first time, but if you come to the page by clicking a button (location.href) it's not firing.  I'm rather confused - if it triggers once, why wouldn't it trigger again?

Comment: I am a bit confused my self.
I don't suppose you can create a fiddle with it, so I can have a look at how the code is structured?